# Highcharts Rails Pie Chart, How to pass label data in to pie chart?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, charts, highcharts

I am trying to get labels to show on a pie chart in ROR. I am using to_json as a parameter:

```
<%=raw @students.to_json %>
```

This works under the categories: tag on a column chart but when I apply it to a pie chart I get a string of all labels like so:

[image: Names]
I'm trying a few things here - some of it clearly wrong. How can I pass the data - which I have - but get the labels to show individually on each portion? How do I format this? Thanks.

```
<script>
 $(function () {
    $('#containers7').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Students and Number of Notes in Value and Percentage'
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return <%=raw @students.to_json %> + '<b>' + this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.point.y
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                name: <%=raw @students.to_json %>,
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels:{
                    enabled: true,
                    format:  <%=raw @students.to_json %>,
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
        series: [{
            colorByPoint: true,
            name: <%=raw @students.to_json %>,
            data: <%= @sData %>
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried taking out "raw" but then nothing renders.

Comment: This might be caused by setting `format` of `dataLabels` to `<%=raw @students.to_json %>`. What does `<%=raw @students.to_json %>` return?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I updated OP. When I take out "raw" the chart does not render.

Comment: But my question still stands: What does `<%=raw @students.to_json %>` return? It would be easier if you could create a live example, like JSFiddle, with exemplary data that your chart is using (so instead of taking out "raw" you could replace it with data that might be or is used).